# Does the CakePHP Auth Component returns a HTTP status before the redirect action?

Tags: cakephp, seo, cakephp-2.0

If a search engine robot tries to access one of my pages that needs to be logged in, does the Auth Component returns a 401 HTTP status or just do a redirect without "telling" the robot that it can't access that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use postman and do a simple test if you wish to. Anyway this is what I got when I tried to access a non authorized page

[image]

Comment: In addition to that, AJAX requests do receive a 403. Changing the type of response for specific clients is something that the application must handle on its own.